# Difference between deployment and enactment

Tags: web-services, service, soa, composition

What is the difference between deployment and enactment? I keep coming across the term "enactment" when I read about choreographies.

Answer (score 0):

You need first understand what is Service Choreography at first place and why it is being Enactment. here is a part of it's wiki which help understanding the process:"Enactment of service choreographies[edit]
Service choreographies are not executed: they are enacted. A service choreography is enacted when its participants execute their roles.[5] That is, unlike service orchestration, service choreographies are not run by some engine on the service infrastructure, but they “happen" when their roles are executed. This is because the logic of the service choreography is specified from a global point of view, and thus it is not realized by one single service like in service orchestration. "take look at this resource [Service choreography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_choreography#Enactment_of_service_choreographies)